# Youtube CommentThread not returning all comments

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to create a small app that can retrieve all the comments from a youtube video.  I am using the Youtube Data API v3 to try and retrieve all the comments, but for some reason it only gives me a fraction of the comments that are on the video.

Thd ID of the video this is being tested on is ozpqv1mYLcE

This is my code that I am using to just count the number of comments right now.  This uses the Auth package from the sample code provided by google.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThread;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThreadListResponse;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.List;

public class YoutubeTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

        try{
            Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "commentthreads");

            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("YoutubeTest").build();

            String videoID = "ozpqv1mYLcE";
            int count = 0;
            String nextPage = null;

            CommentThreadListResponse response = youtube.commentThreads().list("snippet,replies")
                    .setVideoId(videoID).setTextFormat("plainText").setMaxResults(100L).execute();

            nextPage = response.getNextPageToken();
            count += response.getItems().size();
            for(CommentThread t : response.getItems()){
                if(t.getReplies() != null)
                    count += t.getReplies().size();
            }
            int i = 0;

            while(nextPage != null){
                response = youtube.commentThreads().list("snippet,replies")
                        .setVideoId(videoID).setTextFormat("plainText").setMaxResults(100L).setPageToken(nextPage).execute();

                nextPage = response.getNextPageToken();
                count += response.getItems().size();
                for(CommentThread t : response.getItems()){
                    if(t.getReplies() != null)
                        count += t.getReplies().size();
                }
                System.out.println(i++);
            }

            System.out.println("Total Number of Comments: " + count);



        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output from running this is:

```
0
1
Total Number of Comments: 313
```

However at the time of posting this thread the thread has 5049 comments (Can all be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=ozpqv1mYLcE )

I believe that my pagination is correct in my code as well as counting the replies from the threads.  Is this a limitation in the youtube api?  Or am I doing something wrong that I am just not aware of?  Any help in figuring this problem out is greatly appreciated

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you set MaxResults higher?

Comment: You can't. YouTube will respond with an error if you do. That value must be between 1 and 100. No matter what it is set to I still get the same number of comments back

Comment: Just thought of this.  Could it be something that the owner of the youtube channel is restricting?  I have tried my code on a few other videos from different users and it seems to be able to count all the comments.

Comment: Not sure. I tried to comment this morning but the network dropped it... if you get the same results when MaxResults is set *lower*, perhaps you really are getting everything and it's how you count them? Have you examined your results to see what's getting dropped, if anything?

Comment: I did realize I was counting them wrong, and I will update my post later with the new counting method.  However on that particular video it did not change the number much (317 is what I got now).  But if you go to the all_comments link you can clearly see there is well over 300 comments on the video

Comment: Yes, I'm just wondering whether there's an element of recursion or something similar which is causing problems, and which maybe you could spot by looking at which comments you *do* get and which you don't.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however I don't see any recursion or anything similar that would be causing issues.  I found two comments from that page, one in my results and one not.  Both are top level comments and should be included in my results.  Both comments are by youtube accounts, not google plus account.  I can't skip pages of results from youtube as I only have the next page to view, and each returned result has values.  I also manually did this with the youtube api "Try it!" on the documentation page with the same results.

Comment: Somehow, I am not able to retrieve any comments through the API. {
kind: "youtube#commentListResponse"
etag: ""jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/RRUh1tKSlYuVfd9Z-4arDmxP7ZU""
items: [0]
}